Logical Equivalence in Universal Quantification
If I know that $$\forall x\, \big(A(x) \Leftrightarrow B(x)\big)$$ is true, how can I prove that $$\forall x\, A(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y\, B(y)$$
From the perspective of the meaning of quantifiers, this seems obvious, but is there a standard method to prove it?

Question ambiguous.  Is the premise $$[ ~\forall x ~A(x) ~] \iff [ ~\forall x ~B(x) ~]$$ or (more likely) $$\forall x ~[ ~A(x) \iff B(x) ~] ~?$$

It may help to make the domain of discourse explicit as a predicate $D$ as done in most mathematical proofs as follows: $\forall x(D(x) \implies (A(x)\iff B(x)) \implies (\forall x (D(x) \implies A(x)) \iff \forall x (D(x) \implies B(x)))$

...  It looks more "wordy" but it is actually easier to work with IMHO.

Assume that $\forall x (A(x) \Leftrightarrow B(x))$, let us call this hypothesis H1. We show that $\forall x A(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y B(y)$ by separately proving the two directions of the equivalence.
$\Rightarrow$: Suppose $\forall x A(x)$, let us call this hypothesis H2. Take an arbitrary $y$. Because of H2, $A(y)$ holds. Hence, $B(y)$ holds thanks to H1. Since $y$ is arbitrary, this means that $\forall y B(y)$.
$\Leftarrow$: Analogous to the previous point.

Let $f : ∀x\, \big(A(x) → B(x)\big)$,
$\phantom{\text{Let }} g : ∀x\, A(x)$,
$\phantom{\text{Let }} y$ be a variable.
Then $f(y)(g(y)) : B(y)$, or better yet:
$$g : ∀x\, A(x), y ↦ f(y)(g(y)) : ∀x\, A(x) → ∀y\, B(y)$$
And that's it.

The idea is that you write $h : P$ to mean that $h$ is a proof of $P$.
You can evaluate $f$ at $y$ to get $f(y)$ a proof of $A(y) → B(y)$, and this can be evaluated at a proof of $A(y)$ to get a proof of $B(y)$; in this case we have $g(y) : A(y)$.
These are just the elimination rules of $\forall$ and $→$.
Also, $x ↦ h(x)$ is the introduction for $∀$ or for $→$.

If you want to get precise and prove it with $\leftrightarrow$ instead, consider the following:
Let $f : ∀x\, \big(A(x) → B(x) ∧ B(x) → A(x)\big)$.
Then
$$\Big(g : ∀x\, A(x), y ↦ π_1\big(f(y)\big)\big(g(y)\big) \quad , \quad g : ∀y\, B(y), x ↦ π_2\big(f(x)\big)\big(g(x)\big)\Big)$$
is a proof of $\big(∀x\, A(x) → ∀y\, B(y)\big) \ ∧ \ \big(∀y\, B(y) → ∀x\, B(x)\big)$.
Now the pair $(,)$ is the introduction rule for $∧$ and $π_1$ and $π_2$ are the elimination rules for it.
